# hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

git sometimes gives me this message on a conflict (during a revert or cherry pick)

```
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This means that you need to explicitly tell Git that you've resolved a conflict at each file or folder (that is path).

**1. Look at the list of files with yet unresolved conflicts**

```
git status
```

**2. Mark each file as resolved**

Once you have resolved conflicts in a file, add it to mark that conflicts are resolved:

```
git add file-which-had-conflicts
```

If you would like to remove the file instead of resolving conflicts, do it with `git rm`. However, it's a rare case.

```
git rm file-which-had-conflicts
```

**3. Proceed with rebase/merge/whatever**

```
git rebase --continue
git merge --continue
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Comment: `git commit` isn't necessarily the final step, for example during a `rebase`.

Comment: what's the problem when no files except the changelog.md is showing up on `git status`, but i am sure the commit has other changes than only the cnagelog?

Comment: @Gobliins @Gobliins  Please ask a new question and add this information: what does `git diff` return? Are you rebasing/merging or just committing changes?

Comment: @NickVolynkin i was on a different issue today, i will tell you on monday, when i am back on it, what git diff will return

Comment: I use git add with dot: "git add  ." instead "git add"

Comment: @TarasMelnyk sure, all three commands require arguments. Plain `git add` won't do anything.

Comment: Are you saying that by using `git add .` I'm marking a conflict as resolved?

Comment: @Rich `git add file-which-had-conflicts`

Answer (score 5):

because some files are in conflict ,you can type `git status` to find out what is the file with conflict, and after the conflict was sovled ,just `git commit -m sth log` ,at last `git cherry-pick your-commmit-id` . see details http://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Using_Git_Cherry_Pick#Resolve_conflicts

Answer (score 1):

This... can be confusing, and with Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the advice message that "[`git cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/173368d73da792663358dea5b878cc822511001e/Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))</sup> gives is clearer:

When it demands conflicted replay of a commit to be resolved by the end user, it now (Git 2.34, Q4 2021) says:

- for `git cherry-pick`:

```
After resolving the conflicts, mark them with
`git add`/`rm <pathspec>`, then run
`git cherry-pick --continue`

You can instead skip this commit with `git cherry-pick --skip`.

To abort and get back to the state before `git cherry-pick`
run `git cherry-pick --abort`.
```

- for `git revert`:

```
After resolving the conflicts, mark them with
`git add`/`rm <pathspec>`, then run
`git revert --continue`

You can instead skip this commit with `git revert --skip`.

To abort and get back to the state before `git revert`
run `git revert --abort`.
```

See [commit f172556](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f172556b89822693cae70f87c73fe7b6a96b9855) (22 Aug 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 173368d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/173368d73da792663358dea5b878cc822511001e), 10 Sep 2021)</sup>

> ### [`cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f172556b89822693cae70f87c73fe7b6a96b9855): use better advice message
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> "[`git cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f172556b89822693cae70f87c73fe7b6a96b9855/Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))</sup>, upon seeing a conflict, says:
>
> ```
> hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths 
> hint: with `git add <paths>` or `git rm <paths>` 
> hint: and commit the result with `git commit`.
> ```
>
> As if running "`git commit`" to conclude the resolution of this single step were the end of the story.
>
> **This stems from the fact that the command originally was to pick a *single* commit and not a *range* of commits, and the message was written back then and has not been adjusted.**
>
> When picking a *range* of commits, and the command stops with a conflict in the middle of the range, however, after resolving the conflict and (optionally) recording the result with "`git commit`", the user has to run "`git cherry-pick --continue`" to have the rest of the range dealt with, "`--skip`" to drop the current commit, or "`--abort`" to discard the series.
>
> Suggest use of "`git cherry-pick --continue/--skip/--abort` so that the message also covers the case where a range of commits are being picked.
>
> Similarly, this optimization can be applied to [`git revert`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f172556b89822693cae70f87c73fe7b6a96b9855/Documentation/git-revert.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))</sup>, suggest use of "`git revert --continue/--skip/--abort` so that the message also covers the case where a range of commits are being reverted.
>
> It is worth mentioning that now we use `advice()` to print the content of `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP` in `print_advice()`, each line of output will start with "hint: ".

---

"[`git cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c036a145c380e79db5fab5aafb87c4981e11cc9e/Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))</sup> invoked during [`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c036a145c380e79db5fab5aafb87c4981e11cc9e/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L518)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> session lost the authorship information, which has been corrected with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [before 2.44 final](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fc51f00ef18d2c0174ab2fd39d0ee473fd144bd).

See [commit e4301f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4301f73fffacf2ba9fb2042b95de32880381e72) (02 Feb 2024) by [Vegard Nossum (`vegard`)](https://github.com/vegard).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c036a14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c036a145c380e79db5fab5aafb87c4981e11cc9e), 14 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4301f73fffacf2ba9fb2042b95de32880381e72): unset `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP` for 'exec' commands
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Vegard Nossum</sup>

> Running "[`git cherry-pick`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e4301f73fffacf2ba9fb2042b95de32880381e72/Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick))</sup> as an x-command in the rebase plan loses the original authorship information.
>
> To fix this, unset `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP` for 'exec' commands.

---

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bd955d26919e149552f34aacf8a4e6368c26cec), `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` is no longer used.

See [commit 72a8d3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72a8d3f027a5ea04ac453583105b368cd88648cd) (27 Feb 2024) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 184969c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/184969ce1d7c560e0afeaec388939c11a0a990dc), 18 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72a8d3f027a5ea04ac453583105b368cd88648cd): stop setting `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Setting this environment variable causes the sequencer to display a custom message when it stops for the user to resolve conflicts and remove `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`.
> Setting it in "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/72a8d3f027a5ea04ac453583105b368cd88648cd/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> is a vestige of the scripted implementation, now that it is a builtin command we do not need to communicate with the sequencer machinery via environment variables.
>
> Move the conflicts advice to use when rebasing into [`sequencer.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/72a8d3f027a5ea04ac453583105b368cd88648cd/sequencer.c) so we do not need to pass it via the environment.
>
> Note that we retain the changes in [e4301f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4301f73fffacf2ba9fb2042b95de32880381e72) ("`sequencer`: unset `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP` for 'exec' commands", 2024-02-02, Git v2.44.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c036a145c380e79db5fab5aafb87c4981e11cc9e)) just in case `GIT_CHERRY_PICK_HELP` is set in the environment when "`git rebase`" is run.